# How to change hue with ColorMatrixFilter in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, colormatrix

At the moment my game looks something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDerE.jpg

I want to change the hue of background squares so that each level would have different color. I did some research and figured out that I could use ColorMatrixFilter for this. I managed to get code like this to work, which changes the hue:

```
var matrix:Array = new Array();
        matrix = matrix.concat([1, 1, 1, 0, 0]); // red
            matrix = matrix.concat([0, 1, 0, 0, 0]); // green
            matrix = matrix.concat([0, 0, 1, 1, 0]); // blue
            matrix = matrix.concat([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]); // alpha

           back.applyFilter(koe, new Rectangle(0, 0, 640, 480), new Point(0, 0), new ColorMatrixFilter(matrix));
```

However, what I didn't figure out was how exactly the matrix works and how I could get hue value from Photoshop for example and insert it to the matrix, or tween hue from -180 to 180. Like for example, in Photoshop, I can use slider to set "Hue" to to +87 to get desired color.

So how exactly I can insert the Hue value which Photoshop or other image software gives me to this matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ColorMatrix](http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/docs_v2_01/com/gskinner/geom/ColorMatrix.html) utility class by Grant Skinner the `adjustHue` method